# torch7: How to flatten a Tensor?

Tags: lua, torch

I want to **flatten** any general *n*-dimensional `torch.Tensor` but in a way which is computationally optimized. (By "flatten" here, I mean converting a given Tensor to a one-dimensional Tensor which has the same number of elements as the given vector.) I am using the following steps currently to do so:

```
local original_tensor = -- output of some intermediate layer of a conv-net residing in the GPU
local shaping_tensor = torch.Tensor(original_tensor:nElement())
original_tensor = original_tensor:resizeAs(shaping_tensor:cuda())
```

I believe it is slightly inefficient because of `:cuda()` which pushes this new Tensor from memory to the GPU. Can someone please suggest a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical approach is to create a view (thus not actually reshaping the tensor).

```
x:view(x:nElement())
```

which comes directly from official "torch for numpy users" https://github.com/torch/torch7/wiki/Torch-for-Numpy-users

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this solved with the **reshape** command?
See the [documentation](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/maths.md) and this [example](http://torch5.sourceforge.net/manual/nn/index-2-3-11.html)

I assume that you know how to grab the dimensions of **original_tensor**.  Multiply them together to get the vector size.

```
local my_vector = nn.reshape(vector_size, original_vector)
```

Am I missing something?  Is this still not efficient enough?  It should be a highly parallel assignment.